# How to cancel the proxy when installing composer on windows 10?

Tags: composer-php

I am running `Composer-Setup.exe`(from https://getcomposer.org/download/) on windows 10,there is a step like this:

[image]

**Question:**
I don't need proxy,how to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, what I did was to change the proxy value in the windows registry:

Use the command in the run bar **regedit** and after:

hkey_current_user software> environment http_proxy file.

Delete this file or change the value according to your proxy